# using cut for cyclic data

Tags: r, cyclic

i am trying to analyse wind data using the 'cut' command,
i want to set 16 wind directions
how can i cut directions 348.75 till 11.25 to a "0" label?
thank you
eliav

Answer (score 2):

probably this is not a general one and ad-hoc solution, but you can do it by adding 360/16/2 to the direction value:

```
w<- -15:375
direction<-cut((w+360/16/2)%%360,breaks=seq(0,360,length=17),labels=FALSE)-1
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a nice `circular` package to help you work with directional data.